# Angularjs and jQuery mobile slider directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create jQuery mobile directive for Angularjs.

Here's what I come up so far:

The code for AngularJS directive:

```
mcb.directive('jSlider', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            value: '=',
            min: '@',
            max: '@',
            step: '@',
            disabled: '@',
            mini: '@',
            highlight: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'tpl/widget/jslider.htm',
        link: function(s, e, a) {
            e.trigger('create');
        }
    };
});
```

Template for the directive:

```
<label for="{{id}}">{{label}} </label>
<input class="slider"
       type="range"
       name="{{id}}"
       id="{{id}}"
       data-highlight="{{highlight}}"
       min="{{min}}"
       max="{{max}}"
       data-ng-model="value"
/>
```

This code creates the the directive but it's not working, I think the problem is that it doesn't compile properly. I tried add adding

```
compile: function (e, a) {
    e.trigger('create');
},
```

inside directives code, then it kinda worked? (it added properties and everything), but slider is displayed at 0 point, event though I set different, value. I think the problem is that I need  to refresh slider when value is set or changed in some way other that slide event (which is important for application I am building). I tried refreshing slider with this code:

```
compile: function (e, a) {
    e.trigger('create');
    e.find('.slider');
},
```

but it doesn't work, and the code inside "link" function stops working when I add "compile" function.

I am new to angularjs, so I don't quite know how "compile" and "link" functions work, it would be nice if someone could give some references to simple explanation, I think I will need it because I will be needing to attach, start, slide, stop events to the directive.
Anyway, any suggestion, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I come up with solution that works:

```
mcb.directive('jSlider', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            value: '=',
            min: '@',
            max: '@',
            step: '@',
            disabled: '@',
            mini: '@',
            highlight: '@',
            start: '&',
            stop: '&'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'tpl/widget/jslider.htm',
        compile: function (e) {
            e.trigger('create');
            return {
                post: function (s, e, a) {
                    e.find('a').click(function (e) {
                        return e.preventDefault();
                    });

                    e.find('div.ui-slider').find('input[type="range"]').on('slidestop', function () {
                        return s.stop();
                    });

                    e.find('div.ui-slider').find('input[type="range"]').on('slidestart', function () {
                        return s.start();
                    });
                    e.find('div.ui-slider').find('input[type="number"]').change(function () {
                        return s.stop();
                    });

                    s.$watch('value', function () {
                        return e.find('#' + a.id).slider('refresh');
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```